# Print columns with variable spacing in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a file, test.dat:

```
A   1.00         11
AT  2.00         12
ARE 3.00         13
```

If I do some action on the third column and write that to a file

```
x=readdlm("test.dat")    
x[:,3]=x[:,3]*2
writedlm("test2.dat",x)

A   1   22
AT  2   24
ARE 3   26
```

Is there anyway to get this output?

```
A   1.00         22
AT  2.00         24
ARE 3.00         26
```

I understand how to do something similar with @printf on other data, but it doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to achieve here?  Do you want the floats represented with a fixed number of decimals?  Or do you want a very specific number of spaces between your columns?  Or both?

Comment: The best would be to maintain all formating from the input file (both floats and specific spacing between columns). But if that's too much to ask in one question, then the specific spacing between columns is more important... Again, I can do this type of thing `@printf("%d,%d,%10d\n", a[1], a[2], a[3])`, but that only works with 1xN arrays, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Formatted output to the REPL

**@sprintf** and a loop is probably what you want

Assuming test.dat contains the following:

```
A 1 11
AT 2 12
ARE 3 13
```

Then using the julia **@printf** macro, which behaves like C **printf**, the following looks like what you want assuming you want 2 decimal places, 4 spaces total, and 10 spaces dedicated to the last column.

```
julia> x=readdlm("test.dat");
julia> x[:,3]=x[:,3]*2;
julia> for i in 1:size(x,1) @printf("%-3s %4.2f %10d\n",x[i,1],x[i,2],x[i,3]) end
A   1.00         22
AT  2.00         24
ARE 3.00         26
```

### To a file

Embellishing a little, **@sprintf** will output to a string instead of *STDOUT*.  You can fill up an array and then write the whole *String* array.

```
s = Array(String,0);
for i in 1:size(x,1) push!(s,@sprintf("%-3s %4.2f %10d",x[i,1],x[i,2],x[i,3])) end
writedlm("test2.dat",s);
```

#### Julia 0.4 simplification

In Julia 0.4, you can use splatting within **@printf**

```
for i in 1:size(x,1) push!(s,@sprintf("%-3s %4.2f %10d",x[i,:]...)) end
```

### One liner

Or you can use **map** and **do** and a comprehension for more succinct but less readable one liner

#### Julia 0.3

```
writedlm("test2.dat",map([x[i,:] for i in 1:size(x,1)]) do y @sprintf("%-3s %4.2f %10d",y[1],y[2],y[3]) end);
```

#### Julia 0.4

```
writedlm("test2.dat",map([x[i,:] for i in 1:size(x,1)]) do y @sprintf("%-3s %4.2f %10d",y...) end);
```

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. Wasn't able to figure it out. Thought I was going to have to go back to using two/three languages for my work (the whole reason I'm trying out Julia). I'll read up on `map` and `@sprintf`. Thanks again :)